# Webpage Readability/Simplified article for Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing an extension and i am providing option for simplified article. If there is any API available for readability(/mobile based readability), please let me know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a node module to simplify html: https://github.com/yangsibai/node-html-readability。Change the `cheerio` module to jQuery, then you can use this on the client side.

It's base on arc90's algorithm。Google "arc90 readability" you can get many information.